# Putting a "game" inside a game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a simple dice game in python, and thanks to some help from here I have improved upon it, but my troubles start with the fact that I don't know where to start when I wish to implement a coin toss to determine which player is going first.

The dice game code:

```
    import random
    (a, b, c, d) = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(4)]
    a=b=c=d=ta=tb=0
    while ta<100 and tb<100: 
      ta+=a+b
      tb+=c+d 
      (a, b, c, d) = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(4)]
      print("Vai vēlaties mest?")
      mest=input("Y/N==>")
      if mest == "y" or mest=="Y":   
       print("Jūs uzmetāt:")
       print (a,"un",b,"|", a+b+ta,)

       print("Pretinieks uzmeta:")
       print (c,"un",d,"|", c+d+tb)

      elif mest=="n" or mest=="N":
        print ("Jūs zaudējāt")
        print("Jūsu punktu skaits:",ta)
        print("Pretinieka punktu skaits:",tb)
        break
    if ta>=100 or tb>=100:
     print("Spēle beigusies")
     if ta>tb:
       print("Jūs uzvarējāt!")
       print("Jūsu punktu skaits:",ta)
       print("Pretinieka punktu skaits:",tb)
     elif tb>ta:
       print ("Jūs zaudējāt!")
       print("Jūsu punktu skaits:",ta)
       print("Pretinieka punktu skaits:",tb)
```

The coin toss code:

```
    import random
    izvele=[]
    moneta=random.choice(["moneta","cipars"]) 
    print("Izvēlieties Moneta vai Cipars")
    izvele=input("moneta / cipars ==>")
    if izvele==moneta:
      print("Jūs sākat pirmais, monēta nokrita uz",moneta)
    else:
      print("Jūs sākat otrais, monēta nokrita uz",moneta)
```

So all in all, what I wish to achieve is the combination of both of these codes. I want the programm to start with the first code and if the guess is correct the dice game will display the results of a+b+ta first and if the guess is not correct it will display the results of c+d+tb first for the rest of the game.
Also, for the sake of making it more convinient, I also have a question regarding the second code, how do you asign a defining letter to a word from choices, for example if I input m it will recognize it as moneta and so on.
p.s
Sorry for the long question and bad formmating, I am still new to this thing and I want to learn as much as possible

Comment: Are you asking how you can cycle between two players in the while loop and start with a random player? So for example player 2 starts, he makes a choice and then the game asks player 1 to make a choice and so on.

Comment: So the basic jist of the code is, a player plays dice aginst computer. The only choice is made by player. How ever the first choice t.i the coin flip determines whos values will be shown first, if choice==coin the point values of the player are shown first and if not the first values are of the computer for the rest of the game

Comment: It kind of sounds like you could simply generate a random number between 0 and 1 - if 0, the first player goes first, and if 1, the second player goes first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how exactly your code should work, but I think you want to do something like this: First I shuffle a list of the player names, so `player1` is either the human player or the computer. Then you can just check in the rest of the code if the first player `== 'human'` or `== 'computer'`.

Here in my example I just let the user re-roll his die and either change variable `a` if he's the first or variable `b` if he's the second player.

```
import random


players = ['human', 'computer']
random.shuffle(players)
# Assign the shuffled player names to these two variables.
player1, player2 = players

a = random.randint(1, 6)
b = random.randint(1, 6)

# Then print the dice of the players.
print(f'{player1} rolled {a} and {player2} rolled {b}')

user_input = input('Enter "y" to roll again: ')

# Just check if the input starts with 'y'.
if user_input.lower().startswith('y'):
    # Change either variable a or b depending on the first player.
    if player1 == 'human':
        a = random.randint(1, 6)
    else:
        b = random.randint(1, 6)

print(f'{player1} rolled {a} and {player2} rolled {b}')
```

Comment: If you're using an older Python version than 3.6, you have to use the str.format method instead of f-strings: `print('{} rolled {} and {} rolled {}'.format(player1, a, player2, b))`.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to combine the two codes, by simply putting the coin toss code outside the loop and added `if choice==coin` in the loop with one set of printouts and `else` with the other ones. Now I just need to find a way to add another loop which would offer the option to play again after the point values have been reached

Comment: Great! To let the user play again, I'd put the game code into a function and then call it in another outer while loop. When the game is done, just ask the user if s/he wants to play again and if "no" is entered, break out of the while loop to quit.